# Simplifying Multiple Summations for worst case analysis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, fractions

I'm figuring out a worst case analysis on a function. After converting it to a set of summations, and changing the sigma notations into summation formuale I ended up with:

```
N(N+1)(2N+1) / 6    +    N    -     N(N+1) / 2
```

Using LCD i was able to combine the first two components as:

```
 N(N+1)(2N+1) + 6N / 6
```

Leaving me with:

```
 N(N+1)(2N+1) + 6N / 6     -     N(N+1) / 2
```

Using LCD again, I'm guessing I would use an LCD of 6 then combine the two fractions as i did the first. But i am having trouble converting the top line of the second fraction. Do I multiply the whole expression by 3, or just numerics?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}    +    N    -   \dfrac{  N(N+1)}{ 2}$

$=\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}    +   \dfrac{6 N}{6}    -   \dfrac{ 3N(N+1)}{ 6}$

$=\dfrac{N(N+1)(2N+1)    +  6 N    -    3N(N+1)}{ 6}$

and you can simplify the numerator.

Incidentally this is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N i^2+1-i$ so it is quite easy to check your result for various small values of $N$.

Comment: This is what i would have written, but incidentally my friend got toN(N+1)(2N+1-3)+6N/6 I just couldn't understand the missing transition in between.

Answer (score 1):

A good hint would be to write the second fraction as $$\frac{3N(N+1)}{6}$$ and then combine it with the first one.

Comment: Nice hint, my friend! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy for the support. ;-)